# Mongodb projection-->differents property on localhost and production deploy

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mongodb, projection

i develop an app on react on MERN Stack.Server side setup i've created a controller and i've defined a projection in order to spécify the property to send in a json. it works on local with postman . but when i deploy my app, the result of api call is different and all property has display.Do you have an idea why.
i don't understand why some fiels appears on production and not in local

***Controler.js***

ficheMembre: (req, res, next) => {
const projection = [
"contact",
"company",
"social",
"login.emailMember",

```
]; //Ajout d'un projection pour contrôler les datas du json

Adherent.find({ visibility: true }, projection, (error, adherent) => {
  if (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Erreur DB" });
  }
  return res.status(200).json(adherent);
});
```

},

***result in postman localhost:OK***

"contact": {
"civilite": "Monsieur",
"name": "Giordano",
"firstname": "Michaël",
"function": "Fondateur - Réalisateur - Pilote de drone",
"citation": "",
"picture": "http://dev.api.cannesisup.prod.ziosting.net/images/1596186316166_contactPicture.png"
},
"login": {
"emailMember": "contact@azur-360.com"
},

***result in postman production:NOK***

"contact": {
"civilite": "Monsieur",
"name": "Giordano",
"firstname": "Michaël",
"function": "Fondateur - Réalisateur - Pilote de drone",
"citation": "",
"picture": "http://dev.api.cannesisup.prod.ziosting.net/images/1596186316166_contactPicture.png"
},
"login": {
"emailMember": "contact@azur-360.com",
"passwordMember": "$2b$10$80dudUXTfGUYypvDo/xA0.cRBCGErx3whzA3hfrv73qT/4VKWdzva",
"secretQuestion": "Quel est la marque de votre première voiture",
"secretReply": "peugeot"
},

Comment: If you add sample data and results, then someone could help from here

Comment: Have you tried using object projection, {"contact": 1, "company": 1, "social": 1, "login.emailMember": 1}

Comment: hello, i try this to replace array from object with true or false, and the result is equal

ficheMembre: (req, res, next) => {
    const projection = {
      "company": 1,
      "social": 1,
      "contact": 1,
      "login.emailMember": 1,
    }; //Ajout d'un projection pour contrôler les datas du json

    Adherent.find({ visibility: true }, projection, (error, adherent) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Erreur DB" });
      }
      return res.status(200).json(adherent);
    });
  },